# Google Analytics goal

Tags: google-analytics

I need help with setting up Google Analytics Goal. Actually I have set it up but I have problem connecting the site with the goal. I have two optional goals - destination and event. Event goal is supposed fire when a contact form is submitted. The destination form is is exactly the same as a goal but it is fired when redirect url is visited. This url is provided after successful form submission so I think this is the better one.

I have set it up in the GA admin panel but I don't know what to do next. When adding event tracking I need to add the snippet of code in the anchor as an attribute. What should I do now?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, when someone submits your contact form, to they get redirected to another URL in their browser or not?

Comment: Yes but on the same page. They get section that was hidden but it extends the URL. I have tried to do the destination goal but it says that a code needs to be added to the destination page. Since it is the same page I am stuck here.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. So in this case, you'll need to register an event in Google Analytics yes. I'll try and answer very soon for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an onclick push event to the submit button of your contact form.

For example, something like:-

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contact', 'enquiry', 'contact form',, false]);"
```

As an example, this in context would be along the lines of:-

```
<input id=”contact-submit” class=”button” type=”submit” value=”Submit” onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contact', 'enquiry', 'contact form',, false]);">
```

Then, in Google Analytics, you'll need to add the event to correspond with the code used above.

1. Open up the profile you wish to set up the goal in.
2. Click the gear icon in the upper right corner of the Google Analytics interface.
3. Click the Goals tab (in the sub-navigation just below where your Profile is listed)
4. Choose the Goal Set you wish to add the event to.
5. Name your goal and select the Event radio button.
6. Populate the following goal details:

Category | that matches | contact
Action | that matches | enquiry
Label | that matches | contact form
Value | that matches |

1. If you’ve added a Value in step 1, leave the “Use the actual Event Value” radio button selected.
2. Click “Save” and you’re ready to go!

Comment: Thanks a lot Geoff! Your answer has really helped me. Now it works but now I have a problem with Mozilla Firefox 26.0 on Windows. On Mac OSX it works on all browsers but on FF 26.0 on Windows it doesn't. I wasn't able to find anything similar on this matter but it really is frustrating.

If you want to look at yourself you can check it out here

        www.fundamentum.com

There is a form at eh bottom of the page. You can inspect Send button to see the code.

Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Your code looks correct. I just submitted the form via Firefox on Windows 7. I can't see anything wrong frontend. Try clearing Firefox cache maybe.

Comment: Firefox is fresh installed because I don't use it so it is not a matter of cache.

Comment: What exactly isn't happening when using Firefox?

Comment: A goal is not triggered and it is not showing up in Real-time Analytics. Well I don't know if it is not triggered but I know it is not showing up in GA.

Comment: What about outside of real time GA? Can you see the goals recorded from days previous? If it's working for other browsers then it should be working for all. I see you have different event tracking on the other button (internal nav) - does this one track events in Firefox? There is an [alternative solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-visual-form-builder-google-analytics-goal-tracking) for this if it comes to it.

Comment: Geoff I really appretiate your effort but I still have some questions that I think you can help me with. I have decided to have the form redirect to another page on submit and to change Event Goal to Destination one. I am wondering is there any kind of code snippet that needs to be placed on that page or this page will be recognized just by its URL?

Comment: Providing the Google Analytics tracking code is on every page and you've correctly set up a destination goal with this post submission URL as the goal, then these will all be tracked in GA as a goal yes.